# translate site content based on select menu click

Tags: jquery, laravel

The select allows the user to select 1 of 3 languages (English, Spanish and German). The goal is that, if the user selects English, all content of the site changes to English, and the same for the other languages.

However, it is not working. No error appears, but, when the user selects a language in the select menu, the site content is not translated. Do you know why?

The LanguageController:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function changeLanguage(Request $request)
    {
        if(Session::has(locale)){
            session()->put('locale', $request->language);}
        else{
            session()->put('locale', 'en');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Html:

```
    <form method="post" action="{{route('site.translate')}}" id="translate">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <select name="language" id="language">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">German</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

LocaleMiddleware:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class LocaleMiddleware
    {

        protected $languages = ['en','fr','es', 'de'];


        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if(!session()->has('locale'))
            {
                session()->put('locale', $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->languages));
            }

            app()->setLocale(session('locale'));

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Code to submit the form on select menu change:

```
var myFormName = "translate";
$('#language').on('change', function() {
            document.forms[myFormName].submit();
        });
```

Comment: try this [package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: Since you're already using `jQuery`, why not use `$("#translate").submit()` instead of `document.forms[myFormName]`?

Comment: Thanks, but same error with that.

Comment: Thanks, for that package is necessary to make all site routes inside "Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function()"?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, can you try using `id="language"` instead of `name="language"`? The selector in your jQuery code actually expects the id to be "language", not the name.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with that, I already had that but dont works.